# How i can refresh a part of page using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I try to filter information, but I only need that just the table refresh and display the information using javascript, and I can not find a good method to do it

I try to use this code for my page, but I dont know how to implement it

JS

```
    let url="https://server.test-cors.org/server?id=2934825&enable=true&status=200&credentials=false&methods=GET"

    async function refresh() {
          btn.style.visibility= "hidden";
          dynamicPart.innerHTML="Loading..."
          dynamicPart.innerHTML=await(await fetch(url)).text();
          setTimeout(refresh,2000);}
```

HTML of the metod

```
HTML
<div id="staticPart">Here is static part of page
<button id="btn" onclick="refresh()">Start refreshing (2s)</button>
</div>

<div id="dynamicPart">Dynamic part</div>
```

And this is my table in Html

```
<div class='d-flex justify-content-center' id="contentTable">
            <table class='table table-stripped' border=1 id="table">
                <thead class= 'thead-dark'>
                    <tr>
                        <th>#</th>
                        <th>Fecha</th>
                        <th>Documento</th>
                        <th>Nombres</th>
                        <th>Apellidos</th>
                        <th>Sede</th>
                        <th>Siglas</th>
                        <th>Administrador</th>                        
                        <th>Acciones</th>                        
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <a href="/Jomar/users_control/controller/ControlAsisController.php?action=todos"></a>
                    <?php
                        for($i = 0; $i < count($datos); $i++){
                            $id = $datos[$i]['id_controlAsis'];
                            $rutaEd = "/Jomar/users_control/controller/ControlAsisController.php?action=editar&id_controlAsis=$id";
                            $rutaEl = "/Jomar/users_control/controller/ControlAsisController.php?action=eliminar&id_controlAsis=$id";
                            echo "<tr>";
                            echo "<td>". ($i+1) ."</td>";
                            echo "<td> {$datos[$i]['fecha']} </td>";
                            echo "<td> {$datos[$i]['documento']} </td>";
                            echo "<td> {$datos[$i]['nombres']} </td>";
                            echo "<td> {$datos[$i]['apellidos']} </td>";
                            echo "<td> {$datos[$i]['sede']} </td>";
                            echo "<td> {$datos[$i]['siglas']} </td>";
                            echo "<td> {$datos[$i]['administrador']} </td>";                            
                            echo "<td>
                            <a href='$rutaEd' class='badge badge-primary'>Editar </a>
                            <a href='$rutaEl' class='badge badge-warning'>Eliminar </a>
                            </td>";
                            echo "</tr>";
                        }

                    ?>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
```

Thanks for the help, sorry for my English

Answer (score 0):

Making a lot of assumptions. You need to define the 'btn' and 'dynamicPart' variables before you use them.

Example:

```
let btn = document.querySelector("#id_of_some_button_in_html");
let dynamicPart = document.querySelector("#id_of_a_div");
```

Then you just need to call

```
refresh();
```

then the

```
setTimeout(refresh,2000);
```

of your code will run every 2 seconds.

```
let url="https://server.test-cors.org/server?id=2934825&enable=true&status=200&credentials=false&methods=GET"

async function refresh() {
      let btn = document.querySelector("#id_of_some_button_in_html");
      let dynamicPart = document.querySelector("#id_of_a_div");

      btn.style.visibility= "hidden";
      dynamicPart.innerHTML="Loading..."
      dynamicPart.innerHTML=await(await fetch(url)).text();
      setTimeout(refresh,2000);}

refresh();
```

Understanding this is not considered 'good' code, but I am making the assumption that you are just starting to learn JS and this code is not something that will be put into production.

Comment: Thanks, but i have other question, sorry, if i need upload the same content in the div? what i gotta do?  I mean, I have a table in the div and I just need to refresh it, I dont know if you can understand me, but thanks

Comment: You would follow the same logic as my answer. If you understand basic html and javascript it is simply grabbing the area of the table you want to update with `document.querySelector('#id_of_dynamicPart_of_table')`.  I highly suggest you research some free html and javascript tutorials.  Best of luck!